# Why the conditional (ternary) operator does not return the correct value?

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain to me why the "conditional (ternary) operator" does not work properly? I use chrome and below is my sample code snippet.

```
var temp = [1,2,3];
function test(array, n){
//console.log('Inside Function' + array);
//console.log('value of n is ' + n);
//console.log('array length = ' + array.length);
     return n>array.lenght ? array : array.slice(2,array.length);
}

// console.log('Test Index is greater than array length');
var result = test(temp, 5);
console.log(result);
```

In my code n is greater than the length of the array passed into the function test. I expect to get the complete array, not the sliced. 
is there anyone who can help me to explain this.I am new to javascript

Comment: `length`! spelling counts.

Comment: Do you mean to say length does not return the number of elements in the array?

Comment: `length` does indeed do that. But `array.lenght` will be `undefined`. As already said - check your spelling.

Comment: @PraveerKumar unless you type `length` not `lenght`

Comment: @Praveer Kumar issa typo

Comment: oops. I am sorry about this question. yeah, the spelling is incorrect. Many thanks, guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have misspelled `length`

```js
var temp = [1,2,3];
function test(array, n){
//console.log('Inside Function' + array);
//console.log('value of n is ' + n);
//console.log('array length = ' + array.length);
     return n>array.length ? array : array.slice(2,array.length);
}

// console.log('Test Index is greater than array length');
var result = test(temp, 5);
console.log(result);
```